# Is it possible to animate attribute change using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to change the "src" attribute of an "img" element after hovering over its parent element.

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="thumbnail">
    <img src="img/1_thumb.jpg">
</div>
```

And I need to change the src value from "img/1_thumb.jpg" to "img/1_thumb_hov.jpg"

I did it with this jQuery code

```
$('.thumbnail').hover(function() {
    $(this).children(0).attr('src', 'img/1_thumbnail_hov.jpg');
}, function() {
    $(this).children(0).attr('src', 'img/1_thumbnail.jpg');
});
```

But as you can tell, this will only do a fast change and I'd like to make it fade if possible.

Thank you so much, if you can help me solve this.

Comment: If you use CSS `background-image`, you can change it with more CSS (`:hover`), and apply a `transition`. It's not supposed to work, but Chrome at least cross-fades the images!

Comment: why you are not using .thumbnail:hover class in css

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Please [**search before posting**](/search?q=cross+fade+image+jquery), this question has been asked and answered many times. More about searching [here](/help/searching).

Answer (score 0):

Put both images in your container. Set the "hover" one to `opacity:0`. Then use `.thumbnail:hover` and select that second image, to give it `opacity:1`. Slap a `transition: opacity 1s;` on the image and you're done.